# The working of the static imports

Tags: java, static, import, overloading

What I am having is two classes which go like this.

```
public class Class1 {

    public static void staticMethod1(){}

    public static void staticMethod2(){}

    public static void commonStaticMethod(){}

}
```

And class 2 as

```
import static Class1.*;

public class Class2 {

    public static void commonStaticMethod(){}

}
```

And to my surprise, this had compiled without any errors and even warnings. So how the static imports escapes from overloading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static imports are not overloading. They are merely syntactic sugar to make the use of static methods from other classes shorter.

That is, when a method is called that is not available in the current context then it checks the static imports to see if there is a matching static method.

So `staticMethod()` would expand to `SomeOtherClass.staticMethod()`

In your particular case there is no conflict as you do not attempt to call `commonStaticMethod`. Were you to do so the compiler will either complain of an ambiguity or default to the static method in the current class (I'm not to sure which -- I don't use * in static imports). But this is something you can easily check for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You're confused about what a static import does. A static import in class A of B.* only allows calling static methods of B in the code of A without prepending `B.` to the static method call. It has nothing to do with overrides, and doesn't add methods from B to the class A.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're expecting here. You can always override a name from an enclosing scope, or another scope, and all that `import` does is open other scopes.

Comment: Then if I had called the `commonStaticMethod()`, does it calls the method in Class1 or in Class2?

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati It depends entirely where you called it from. If you called it from within Class2, you get Class2's version. Same in a scope where you had done `import static Class2.*` and there were no overrides. If it was in the scope of Class1 you would get Class1's, as you would if you had done `import static Class1.*` and there were no overrides. And of course if you had done both imports you would get an ambiguity compilation error.

Comment: You probably meant hide vs. override.

Comment: @assylias No thanks, I meant override. The compiler does the hiding: the programmer does the overriding.

Answer (score 0):

You have just hidden the `commonStaticMethod` of Class1 in your Class2.

You would get the error you expected if you do static import of 2 classes having same method and you try to use that method in your class.

Comment: @chaitanya10 Redefine is quite the right terminology. rather are you doing is "hiding" the other static method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no overloading since `Class2` does not extend `Class1`. There is hiding in that since `Class2` has a method name that is the same as the one imported, any unqualified reference to this method name will assume the local instance. To use the imported one you must qualify the method with `Class1.commonStaticMethod`